# Socket.io Multiple messages emitted from one event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been looking for quite a while for a solution but haven't found anything yet.

I'm trying to emit a message from a server every time the server sees that a file has changed in a specified directory.  However, instead of only emitting one message, it insists on emitting the same message three times.  I am using chokidar to watch the directory, and inside of the 'change' event I emit the message.
Server side code:

```
var   express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , http = require('http')
    , server = http.Server(app)
    , io =require('socket.io')(server)
    , chokidar = require('chokidar');
server.listen(1234);
app.use('/public', express.static( __dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    var ipAddress = request.socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log("New express connection from: " + ipAddress);
    response.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); //Server client
});




 var watcher = chokidar.watch("temp", {ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true});

    watcher.on('change', function(path){
        console.log(path + " has changed.");
        fs.readFile(path,'utf8', function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                var json = JSON.parse(data), recPsec, type;
                recPsec = json.data[0].values[0];
                type = json.data[0].values[16];
                var compiled = {
                                                    "recPsec" : recPsec,
                                                    "type"      : type
                                             }
                var jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(compiled)
                io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify(jsonMessage));
                console.log("Sent message");
            }

        });

    });
watcher.on('unlink', function(path){
    console.log('File: ', path, ' has been removed');
});

watcher.on('add', function(path){
    console.log("hi");
    fs.readFile(path,'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
        var json = JSON.parse(data), recPsec, type;
            recPsec = json.data[0].values[0];
            type = json.data[0].values[16];
            var compiled = {
                                                "recPsec" : recPsec,
                                                "type"      : type
                                         }
            var jsonMessage = compiled;
            io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify(jsonMessage));
            console.log("message sent");
        }
        //fs.unlinkSync(path);
    });
});
```

Client Side:

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        socket.on('message', function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            recPsecNew = parsed.recPsec;
            typeNew = parsed.type;
            analyze(recPsecNew, typeNew);
        });
```

I am using socket.io in conjunction with express 4. 
Chokidar is found here: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Logs from the console if I change the name of a file twice are shown here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=95726281991906625675

Comment: Is `console.log(path + " has changed.");` also called three times?

Comment: No it is only called once. I believe the error might be coming from watcher.on('add', function(path){....

Comment: for what it's worth I encountered this same error with socket.io behind some custom redis publish-subscribe event handlers. according to logs in the redis message handler the redis event only fired once but the corresponding websocket would receive 3 messages as well. good luck, I would also really like answer here.

Comment: @batchi Can you add your console output and socket.io logs? Should be easy to track down what is causing the extra messages with that info.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am experiencing this and it is causing me some serious headache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried lodash's Function?

Probably you can use [lodash.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) function

According to its docs:

```
_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options])
```

Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked. The debounced function comes with a cancel method to cancel delayed invocations. Provide an options object to indicate that func should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the wait timeout. Subsequent calls to the debounced function return the result of the last func invocation.